# Присвоение двух значений одному textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

Подскажите как значения из двух текст боксов присвоить одному и добавить между ними запятую?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы о тексте подойдет простой код:

```
textBox3.Text = textBox1.Text + "," + textBox2.Text;
```

В случае если нужно в число перевести:

```
Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text + "," + textBox2.Text);
```

Comment: Почти подошел. Только там и текст и числа.

Comment: Используйте Convert.ToInt32(значение) или Convert.ToString(значение) если хотите что-либо превратить в строку, или число. Можно еще Convert.ToDouble(значение).